# Elasticsearch (NEST client) - How to search across multiple indices using OIS

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to search across multiple indices using OIS(Object Initializer Syntax).
I have seen examples of executing search across multiple indices with Fluent DSL, but I still do not know how to execute an equivalent search with OIS.

Here is my OIS search(Only searching against one index) :

```
        var searchResult =
            await _client.LowLevel.SearchAsync<string>(ApplicationsIndexName, "application", new SearchRequest()
            {

                From = (query.PageSize * query.PageNumber) - query.PageSize,
                Size = query.PageSize,
                Query = GetQuery(query), 
                Aggregations = GetAggregations()
            });
```

Which modifications can be done, so I can search across multiple indices?

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I found out how to search across multiple indices:

```
        var searchResult =
            await _client.LowLevel.SearchAsync<string>(new SearchRequest()
            {
                IndicesBoost = new Dictionary<IndexName, double>
                {
                    { "applications", 1.4 },
                    { "attachments", 1.4 }
                },
                From = (query.PageSize * query.PageNumber) - query.PageSize,
                Size = query.PageSize,
                Query = GetQuery(query), 
                Aggregations = GetAggregations()
            });
```